# Using custom dimension for segmenting in Google Analytics API produces unexpected results, why?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using custom dimension to send over session ids to Google Analytics, like this:

```
 ga('set', 'dimension1', '#{session.id}');
```

Now, I want to be able to retrieve couple of things from Google Analytics, precisely:

- age
- gender
- affinity category
- country

I know that, I can query Google Analytics API for some of these and get number of events segmented by demographic data, like for instance using this query:

```
 dimension: 'ga:userGender', 
 metric: 'ga:totalEvents',  
 sort: '-ga:totalEvents'
```

gets me number of events, segmented by gender.

Also, I know I can combine segments:

```
 dimension: 'ga:country, ga:userGender', 
 metric: 'ga:totalEvents',  
 sort: '-ga:totalEvents'
```

that gets me combination of countries and gender, with number total events

```
 ["Pakistan", "male", "49"], ["Poland", "female", "43"],
```

Having the custom dimension set, I can use `ga:dimension1` for segmenting:

```
 dimension: 'ga:dimension1, ga:country', 
 metric: 'ga:totalEvents',  
 sort: '-ga:totalEvents'
```

and that produces a result, of each sent `session.id` with a country. This way I can determine a session's country.

```
 ["6121235920b4365dde5ab2e655f762f9", "France", "81"],
 ["bc81272332c73b616120f84e5aa89894", "United Kingdom", "78"],
 ["8b9b4ee3ecbe253e07c44ad26e36fa0e", "Netherlands", "70"],
```

However, when I try to combine that custom dimension with other demographic segments, then GA returns empty results.

```
 dimension: 'ga:dimension1, ga:userGender', 
 metric: 'ga:totalEvents',  
 sort: '-ga:totalEvents'
```

gives me nothing, not even an error.

Why is that? Why is custom segment combined with a country segment producing a result, and when combined with userGender segment then it is returning nothing?

Comment: That custom dimension's scope is set to "User". Used to be set to "Session". Both situations produce [] results.

Comment: In the interface when you create a segment that comprises very few users demographic reports will fail, either - there seems to be a minimum threshold of sessions in your segment; AFAIK the given reason are privacy concerns. I assume that also applies to the API.